# Add animated GIF to email/sms/whatsapp

Tags: android, gif, animated, emoticons

I was wondering how to get to add some custom designed animated GIF emoticons to native applications in android like SMS/EMAIL and to other applications like Whatsapp?

I know how to display an animated Gif in Android using AnimationDrawable object. I just want to know if it's possible to do the following:

1) Add custom animated images to Whatsapp application.
2) Add custom animated images to SMS/EMAIL in some easy way?

Just give me hints. I have been looking everywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the application explicitly provides hooks for you to extend its configuration with particular animations/images there is no way to add any content to the existing application APKs. As far as I can tell the whatsapp application and the default email and sms apps do not provide extension hooks, so you won't be able to do this.